# What does it mean that humans can never write (produce) Qur'an?

Tags: quran, science, scientific-proof

Salam,

Qur'an says that even the combined work force of humans and Jinns could not create something like Qur'an or Qur'an itself , let far go human alone.

> Surely, if mankind and jinn were to get together to produce the like of this Qur'an, they will never be able to produce the like of it, howsoever they might help one another.[Al Israa 17: 88]

> Oh people, if you doubt the heavenly origin of this Book which We have sent down to Our servant, the Prophet, produce one surah like it.” [Al Baqarah 2:23]

Let the **number** of arabic letters (alphabets) in Qur'an be *X* (*X* maybe in the order of 10⁷ to 10⁹, or even more , but finite) . Let *S* denotes the set of all books having *X* letters where each letter is of Arabic language. Clearly, *X* is finite, *S* is a finite set and *S* also contains Qur'an.

Obviously humans ***can*** command a computer ( or a supercomputer ) to write all the elements (books) of *S*, and certainly Qur'an would also be written among all the possible books ( in a finite time).

So, how is it possible that humans could never write Qur'an given that Qur'an is having a finite length (of text) and just a particular permutation of *X* letters
which can be produced by a computer program in a finite time ?

**NOTE**: One may argue that Allah will never let humans use a supercomputer to do this task or a supercomputer will freeze if commanded to do so due to order of Allah, etc. and hence the verse is correct that humans would never produce it. ***BUT*** I am asking about the capability of humans that they can create Qur'an or not by themselves and the apparent contradiction to Qur'an. I'm not asking that it would happen in our real life or not.

Thanks !

Comment: In what world is creating every possible set of characters considered writing a book? This is an extremely poor understanding of language. And in what world is something that can never happen "capability"? Would you say we can know the unseen because we can make an infinite series of characters that technically contain every true fact? (and also contain every false fact, like your books also contain every false book so you know the supercomputer isn't from God)

Comment: @TheZ The supercomputer will write all books containing Arabic letters of length *X* with all possible permutation. Why do you think it is not a book writing ? I wrote that paragraph of capability to not let anyone write weird predictions like god will throw supercomputers into hellfire to fulfil the statement of Quran etc. Further, I do not claim that we can know unseen with an infinite series containing all characters, because characters are used by humans which ***may*** not be powerful enough to understand everything. Moreover, I am certainly not claiming that a supercomputer is from God.

Comment: @TheZ Further, the Qur'an says to just **produce** and not by a specific criteria of book-writing prevalent in a specific era of time . It is apparent that Qur'an being a miracle till the day of resurrection should not be susceptible to the ways developed by humans if they attempt to produce so.

Comment: I have no idea in what way writing every random book can be considered producing something like the Quran. You are intentionally misinterpreting the Quran and what it is saying. The point of the challenge is for humans and Jinn to produce something like the Quran, not write every random thing. By definition, everything random does contain the Quran and humans can write random things. But, that is clearly not the point.

Comment: One of the ways the Quran is unique for example is that it makes only true prophecies and narrates true stories. If humans wrote everything, they will not only make true prophecies or tell true stories.

Comment: And no verse in the Quran uses the word "produce" that is just a translation. All of them say "bring" a Surah like it. Making a list of every random Surah can in no way be considered bringing something like the Quran until you actually tell us which one is like the Quran and bring it so we can analyze it.

Comment: The miracle of the Quran is not about physical impossibility. In fact, very much not. The miracle of the Quran is about practical impossibility. The point is: It is impossible for Muhammad (SAW) to produce this Quran, and if you claim it is possible, show it.

What humans can do theoretically is not the problem. What they can do practically is the problem.

Comment: @TheZ If I understand you correctly, then your comment implies that Qur'an can be produced by humanity and it's inventions ( computer ), but cannot be written in a specific way as described by you , right ?

Comment: @TheZ Accordingly, I'll change the title.

Comment: @downvoter Please trouble yourself to explain the reason through which the post can be made better !

Answer (score 0):

Asallamu Alaikum.
I'm a new muslim as of march 11, and I'm blind. I made my account here to see if I could help my brothers and sisters with any questions. So when the quran speaks about producing a book like it, it is refering to the poetic nature of the quran. Let's break this down further.
So in 7 century Arabia, you have to remember that the arabs were masters of their language. In history, just about every society was famous for something. the romans with their coliseums, the greeks with their philosofical developments, and the arabs with their poetry. In fact, when people wanted to badmouth someone, they didn't spew swares like today. Instead, they used poetry to diss other tribes and other people the arabs were having issues with, like a diss war of sorts.
There are 5 catigories of speech that each poem fit into. Let's look at them. We had:

1. Normal speech
2. Rhyme pros
3. Poetry
4. Rhetoric
5. fortune teller and seuthsayer speech
   Every single speech produced at that time could be catigorized and confined into these compartments, and not only that, but poetry in and of itself was comprised into 16 different forms, all known by the people at that time, at least those who could read. With this knolege, let's talk about how this relates to quran.
   The thing about quran is that it was unable to be confined to none of these compartments, neither of speech nor forms of poetry. It was so different, that it completely awed all of the people who knew the prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him. Why you might wonder? well we have to remember that the prophet was iliterate. He bairly traveled outside the arabian Peninsula, and he never went to seak education. But all of a sudden, he was out here reciting the most poetic peace the arabs have ever heard.
   In fact, when the prophet first started, the arabs sent some of the best poets in their time to go investigate and see where he was getting this poetry from. this would be equivalent to a kid you grew up with, and you knew he never ever went to school, who all of a sudden started spouting the most suffisticated educated rhetoric beyond even your knolege in a society with no internet, computers or media content. When the arabs came back, and these were some of the finest poets mind you, they came back and basically said they have no idea where he was getting this from, so they invented the excuse that it was sourcery.
   There's one more miricle in this regard about the quran. When you look at every chapter, you find that 1, its completely different to the one previous, and 2., every single chapter has at least 1 new word in arabic, which uses an already known rootword so the people can interpret its meaning. this is why that now in the modern arabic language spoken today, the credit goes to quran for 70 to 80 percent of the words used today by all arabic speakers.
   So now that we know the miraculous nature of quran, the quran is asking you to basically replicate it. Its asking you to come up with a chapter with the same amount of eloquence, uniqueness and confinement, or lack there of, of every single catigory of arabic speech and poetry. In fact, there have been attempts. If you'd like, I can link you to a video, where a brother even attempted to make chat gpt, one of the most powerful supercomputers on the market, produce something with a similar nature as quran, and even it, despite knowing all the catigories, admitted that 1, it couldn't even come close to producing something as eloquent as quran, and 2, it didn't have sufficient knolege or understanding to be able to produce something as eloquent as quran.
   I hope I was able to break this down in a way where you and other brothers and sisters can understand, and I hope you will be able to realize that the miraculous nature of the quran proves  it couldn't have been from anyone, other than our glorious creator.
   Thanks for reading, hope you enjoyed that nerd rant.
   To the individual which said that the quran could be produced with the help of a supercomputer, this is false. there have been several attempts done, using several different supercomputers and artificial intellegence units which can generate whole essays and books faster than I can even type. Again, I must remind you that even the finest poets in the arabian peninsula were shocked with the uniqueness of the poetry of the quran. So no, quran can't even be replicated with a supercomputer. In fact, if you look up on dawahwise, there was an attempt on that as well. I'll link it here to make your life easier.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAd7Nn1wagEThis should shed some insite. So the criteria is to produce something which does not conform to any of the catigories of arabic poetry at that time, which not even supercomputers can do.

Comment: Reciting extraordinary poetry is not very uncommon. There were many great poets and saints who were illiterate.

Comment: Further, your interpretation is that the unparallel-ness of Quran is only within it's poetry eloquence. So the challenge is to produce something that eloquent which can be easily done by a program ran in a computer/supercomputer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a an expert on Quran (studied but not in a formal setting), however, I do have a background in Mathematics and CS to address this question as it is posed.

1. Your question asks if, given that there was no Quran, could a computer given enough juice and time produce a book among  the N (“finite”) books exactly like it? You would need to create all of them, read all of them, and then pick the one that is exactly the same. That, in itself is extremely exhaustive and would be basically impossible (longer then the universe has existed and will exist - unless Allah wills).

Let's take some math (simple, ballpark, rough). Assume we forget the spaces in the Quran (which eliminates a ton of computation already, this is done for simplicity of already known number of letters in Quran 327,792 (Google)). The total letters in Arabic is 28, excluding spaces. Take 28 letters and for each of the 327,792 total letters, if all lined up we allowed one of the 28 letters in each spot of the 327,792 with repetition we have 28^327792. This is an insanely big number… Now imagine making that 29 and including spaces… let’s continue the argument and take the fastest super computer now (known) which is 442 x 10^15 calculations per second. That’s 442 quadrillion per second. Divide that first number by this and you have the number of seconds it’ll take for that machine assuming perfect programming etc in place. The amount of seconds will exceed the amount of time all of the universe has existed (scientifically). This is only to generate the entire possible collections without checking that list for which one it could be. You could adjust this to find the probability that given K random attempts you somehow generated the Quran (the probability is rounded to 0%). Dictionary attacks are out of question since you would have to assume such Quran was not existent in the first place and you had no list of uniquely possible words.

2. There is no contradiction, the universe would (according to judgment and it’s allotted time unknown to man) would cease this attempt and therefore it would never see the light of day.

Even trying to brute force or dictionary create a verse/surah/chapter **like** it is impossible. Sure you can recreate the same one that Allah has given us already (known knowledge), but what did that prove? Producing anything like (the challenge) it would require knowledge past our capacity partnered with anyone. Take Surah Kawthar (shortest surah) and produce an Arabic surah like it with all of the elements each surah has (theme, rhyme, structure, length, and ability to convey, etc). Translate it or attempt to give it to a believer and see if they believe in its message. The truth of the Quran and firm, protected, and it is finished. A believer would never fall for it.

Comment: The challenge is not to create a book and then search it for our use. It's just only to create the book. The computers and computations are become exponentially efficient nowadays. Further, It doesn't matter if the time is very long or not because it's finite which serves enough for the purpose of question.

Comment: Well, since time is fixed and Allah’s guarantee is that the Quran and works like it cannot be produced, the conclusion one would reach is that yes it can technically (and if Allah had not made it a challenge) be possible. But it is 100% impossible since Allah has said so. Anything (Allah willing) given enough time in our finite universe is possible. The Quran is protected from such since it would never happen in reality.

Comment: Also computers are not that efficient, this problem is on an O(n^n). Creating the book would only happen in a reality outside of ours.